# MySQL | Left join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have something like this:

```
ID | post_author | post_date | ... | post_title | post_status | ... | post_type
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1           | 2007-08-11| ... | A          | publish     | ... | post
2  | 3           | 2007-08-12| ... | B          | publish     | ... | post
3  | 1           | 2007-08-12| ... | C          | publish     | ... | post
4  | 1           | 2007-08-13| ... | D          | publish     | ... | post
5  | 3           | 2007-08-13| ... | E          | publish     | ... | post
```

What I like to do is to get the amount of posts by user and the title and ID of the last post. Based on above data the result should be that:

```
AuthorID | TotalPosts | PostID | PostTitle
------------------------------------------
1        | 3          | 5      | E
3        | 2          | 4      | D
```

What I have tried is this:

```
SELECT 
    p1.post_author         AS  Author,
    count(p1.post_author)  AS  Posts,
    p2.post_title          AS  Title
FROM 
    wp_posts AS p1
LEFT JOIN
    wp_posts As p2
ON
    p1.ID = p2.ID
WHERE
    p1.post_type   =   'post'
AND
    p1.post_status =   'publish'
GROUP BY
    p1.post_author
ORDER BY
    Posts   DESC,
    p2.post_date   ASC
LIMIT
    2
```

The problem is that I always get the title of the first post and not the title of the last post. Is there a way to get the title of the last inserted post ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want the latest title for every author, you can use an inline correlated subquery. This will be relatively fast with proper indexes - especially if you only want results for the 2 most published authors:

```
SELECT 
    post_author         AS  Author,
    COUNT(*)            AS  Posts,
    ( SELECT   p2.post_title
      FROM     wp_posts AS p2
      WHERE    p2.post_author = p1.post_author
        AND    p2.post_type = 'post'
        AND    p2.post_status = 'publish' 
      ORDER BY p2.post_date DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )                   AS  Title
FROM 
    wp_posts AS p1
WHERE
    post_type   =   'post'
AND
    post_status =   'publish'
GROUP BY
    post_author
ORDER BY
    Posts   DESC
LIMIT
    2 ;
```

Comment: There was a mistake in the correlated subquery. It's now corrected.

Comment: I would try to get rid of `ORDER BY` in subquery.

Comment: The `ORDER BY p2.post_date DESC` is actually not needed there. It can be replaced with `AND p2.post_date = MAX(p1.post_date) ORDER BY anything`. But I don't see any reason to avoid `ORDER BY`.

Comment: ORDER BY adds extra processing cost. Cost of Sort is Theta(N^2), while cost of Max is Theta(N). Unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT p.post_author, p3.id, p3.post_title, COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) PostCount
FROM wp_posts p
   JOIN (
    SELECT Max(Post_Date) max_post_date, post_author
    FROM wp_posts
    GROUP BY post_author) p2
     ON p.post_author = p2.post_author
   JOIN wp_posts p3 on p.post_author = p3.post_author
    AND p2.max_post_date = p3.post_date
GROUP BY p.post_author, p3.id, p3.post_title
```

This assumes only one date per post.  If not, is your ID field your max field as well?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check whether this option is faster or not:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.post_title FROM
    (SELECT 
        post_author         AS  Author,
        COUNT(*)            AS  Posts,
        Max(ID) AS MaxID
    FROM 
        wp_posts AS p
    WHERE
        post_type   =   'post' AND
        post_status =   'publish'
    GROUP BY post_author
    ORDER BY Posts   DESC
    LIMIT 2) t1 LEFT JOIN wp_posts t2 
                 ON t1.MaxID= t2.ID
```

Comment: `MAX(id)` is not equivalent to `MAX(post_date)`

Comment: @ypercube well, this depends on implementation no doubt. But I am sure there must we a way to do this without `ORDER BY`, even if ID and post_date are not correlated.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY
p2.post_date DESC,
Posts   DESC
```